# Один пункт меню внизу, остальные вверху в меню

Tags: android, android-layout

Я недавно начал делать новое приложение. Сейчас я делаю меню. У меня есть пункты выбора города, они должны быть посередине и пункт настройки, который должен быть внизу: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я делаю меню вот так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group
        android:id="@+id/cities"
        android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/town_1"
            android:title="Town 1" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/town_2"
            android:title="Town 2" />
    </group>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/settingsMenu"
        android:title="@string/settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings"/>

</menu>
```

А применяю меню вот так:

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/dlMain"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".ui.activities.main.MainActivity">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/main_background">

    ...

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nvMain"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:menu="@menu/main_menu"/>
```

Кто знает как изменять положение отдельных пунктов меню?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете вложить в ваш Navigation свой Layout и там расположить что угодно и как угодно:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navi_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start|top">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            // вот тут распологайте свои  View как угодно
        </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Comment: а если это должен быть тоже пункт меню, который будет вести в другой фрагмент, то как реализовать что бы пункт подсвечивался когда виден этот фрагмент? Менять бэкграунд пункта вручную?

Comment: @DenBondd, это уже отдельный вопрос. В любом случае вручную - это не правильное слово. Программно можно выставить.

Comment: Отслеживаете какой фрагмент выбран в данный момент и программно задаёте нему формат выделения